# Работа с картинками через GDI+ VS DirectX

Tags: c#, .net, directx, gdi, gdi+

Допустим, имеется задача преобразовать N картинок из одного формата в другой, с последующей сменой размера картинок, уменьшение качества картинок и т п вещи.

Имеется ПК с Core i5 и видеокарта, которая поддерживает `DirectX` 9 с 512 МБ ОЗУ.

Интересует следующее:

1. Выполнится конвертирование через `DirectX` быстрее, чем через `GDI+` ?
2. Предоставляет ли .NET какие-то обертки над `DirectX`, похожие на `GDI+` по юзабельности?
   Я знаю, что WPF использует для отрисовки аппаратное ускорение. Можно ли воспользоваться какими-то его примитивами.
3. Какой подход используется в популярных пакетных конвертировщиках?
   Они используют `GDI+` или пишут свое более быстрое решение, которое не использует `GDI+`(Т.е опять же CPU зависимые) или используют аппаратные возможности?

Comment: Посмотрите [Magick.Net](http://magick.codeplex.com/) - работа с [imagemagick](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) в c# - удобно, юзабельно.Внутри DirectX не используется, своё быстрое решение. Если вам ехать, а не шашечки -- вполне нормальное решение.

Comment: @AK, спасибо, но все равно хотелось получить ответы на 3 вопроса.

Answer (score 4):

Как раз таки, DirectX использует аппаратное ускорение, у GDI с этим проблемы.
.NET с шарпом имеют SharpDX - это как раз что то вроде обертки над DirectX, юзать не сказать что удобно, но в сравнении с тем же на Си++ разница чувствуется.

Answer (score 4):

По сути я могу ошибаться, но скажу следующее: Приходилось работать с изображениями, с их генерацией, и в наследие доставался код на WinForms (с отрисовкой на GDI+), из которого сразу было решено выпилить любое упоминание WinForms и сделать всё это на том, что есть в WPF.

1) Работать стало быстрее, а если еще, как вы говорите конвертацию - сделайте её в пуле потоков Parallel.ForEach(); Тогда вообще будет очень хорошо. Только про потокобезопасность не забывайте.

2) Да, представляет. Может не в таком обилии как GDI+, но стоит разобраться и вам этого достаточно будет. Можно дополнить сторонними библиотеками на крайний случай.

3) Они используют как и CPU, так и GPU. Вообще использованием ресурсов занимается сам DX и пиковой производительности добиваются их совместным использованием.

PS. Если я в чём-то не прав, то критика приветствуется.